# bind three different ICollectionView to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mef

I used MVVM and MEF and I created three class that have a ICollectionView.I imported three class into the class that be seted DataContext of View.I want do actions as remove selecteditem and add selecteditem that Commands be declared in three class.I cant bind three IcollectionView to listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) class to allow multiple collections to be displayed in a single list.